# PHP Time Comparison Is Failing

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin and having problems with a time comparison. I basically want: if selected time is before current time, do the thing... but it's not working.

The validation is failing if `expire` is less than five hours ahead of the time(). I correct this by adding the gmt offset `expire` but then it still fails. Any ideas?

```
//$_POST['expire'] = '2019-01-31T12:00';

if(validateDate($_POST['expire'])) {
    $expires_epoch = (strtotime($_POST['expire']) - (get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS));
    if($expires_epoch < time()) {
        ...do the thing...
    }
 }
```

Any thoughts? It seems simple but it doesn't seem to be working the way I'd like it to.

Comment: What is date.timezone into your php.ini. Print using ini_get function and verify. Based on time zone it will give current time.

Comment: Show some example values for the input.

Comment: Input is an ISO8601 time: `2019-01-31T12:00`, which would then be converted to a timestamp via strtotime

Comment: Any reason not to use a `DateTime` object?

Comment: That would be fine with me if it worked. I think it's just not a very "wordpressy" solution, but at this point I'd try anything!

Comment: Shouldn't you just add the timezone offset instead of subtracting it? After all, the timezone offset can be positive or negative and will take care of the subtraction automatically.

Comment: @SalCangeloso Can you please let me know what is the value of "$_POST['expire']" and how can the user select this?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, he said in the 3rd comment that the value is an ISO8601 time looking like 2019-01-31T12:00. And since it's a post, it could be submitted using a form and selected via a calendar widget. Or it could be entered manually.

Comment: Please provide example of value that fails and the time. Your code looks OK except may be the clock you're looking at is using a different timezone than the server. In which case no action is necessary.

Comment: @SalmanA when you say "clock" is different than the server, which clock do you mean? I can tell you that my local timezone (ET) is different than the server (UTC), which is the core problem here.

Comment: @Sal yes that is what I meant. Something that you think should expire at "12AM" will actually expire at 5AM your time. The solution is to remove ambiguity from the input: `2019-01-31T12:00` should be specified as `2019-01-31T12:00-05:00`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) is limited in the formats it can accept and will not always provide the desired results. To avoid the ambiguity of the date formats, as the PHP documentation recommends an alternative is to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Which will allow you to enforce a desired format of the supplied `$_POST['expire']`.

Using the format `Y-m-d\TH:i|` rule, enforces the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) format, excluding the seconds and timezone. The `|` (pipeline) resets the remainder seconds to `:00`, otherwise PHP will use the current seconds.

If you want your code to run **AFTER** the expiry date has elapsed, you then just need to compare `expire_date < current_date`.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/EelYY

```
//current date is 2019-01-04 08:33:30
//$_POST['expire'] = '2019-01-04T08:32';

if ($expire_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i|', $_POST['expire'])) {
    $current_date = new \DateTime();
    if ($expire_date < $current_date) {
        /* example purposes only */
        $diff = $expire_date->diff($current_date);
        echo 'Expired ' . $diff->format('%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds') . ' ago';
        //do the thing
    }
} else {
    die('Invalid Date Format Provided');
}
```

**Result**

```
Expired 0 years 0 months 0 days 0 hours 1 minutes 30 seconds ago
```

---

For clarification on how and why to use the timezone offset from Wordpress.

PHP by default will use the `date.timezone` specified in your `php.ini` when working with `date()`, `time()`, `strtotime()` and `DateTime` objects. This is only important for Wordpress and most other applications when *displaying* dates generated by your app to the viewer or when accepting a date string from a user that is to be saved and displayed to other users. Such as displaying when a post was created or when an event is expected to take place. Otherwise the user timezone offset can generally be ignored, since PHP will apply the native timezone offset to the parsed date(s).

For example, the default PHP `date.timezone` is UTC. I create an event that I want to take place at `2019-01-01 09:00` my time (EST). But the event will start for someone in California (PST) 3 hours prior at `2019-01-01 06:00`.

In order to display the event to other users, the date has to be converted from the user timezone offset of EST to UTC and stored in the database. Then converted from UTC to be displayed as other timezone(s).

### Example: https://3v4l.org/vA97A

```
$defaultTZ = new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
$event_start = '2019-01-01 09:00';
//event starts at 2019-01-01 09:00 EST
$est_date = new \DateTimeImmutable($event_start, new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
//convert to native date to save in database
$utc_date = $est_date->setTimeZone($defaultTZ);
$db_date = $utc_date->format(DATE_ISO8601);

//event starts at 2019-01-01 14:00 UTC
$db_event_start = '2019-01-01T14:00:00+0000';
$event_date = new \DateTimeImmutable($db_event_start, $defaultTZ);

//display the start times to users
$pst_date = $event_date->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
$est_date = $event_date->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo 'Event Starts at:';
echo $event_date->format('Y-m-d H:i T');
echo $pst_date->format('Y-m-d H:i T');
echo $est_date->format('Y-m-d H:i T');

//display event status
echo 'Event ' . ($event_date <= new \DateTime('now', $defaultTZ) ? 'Has' : 'Not') . ' Started';
```

**Result**

```
Event Starts at:
2019-01-01 14:00 GMT+0000
2019-01-01 06:00 PST
2019-01-01 09:00 EST
Event Has Started
```

> For WordPress you would generally replace `date_default_timezone_get()` with
>   `get_option('timezone_string')` to use the application timezone offset instead of PHP's default timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are calculating gmt_offset incorrectly, for WordPress I will do such calculation something like that,

```
$gmt = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
$expires_epoch = strtotime('midnight') + ((24 - $gmt) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
if($expires_epoch < time()){ ... }
```

This will not be the exact solution as I don't know what **(strtotime($_POST['expire'])** exactly is?

Comment: `(strtotime($_POST['expire'])` is the conversion of my ISO8601 time to a timestamp which I then want to compare to time() to see if `expire` is in the past or not

Comment: In that case, have you tried changing the second line with this `$expires_epoch = (strtotime($_POST['expire']) + ((24 - $gmt) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS);` ? It should work for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this code and it worked for me, please check this.

```
    if(validateDate($_POST['expire'])) {
        $expires_epoch = strtotime($_POST['expire']);
        if($expires_epoch < time()) {
            echo '...do the thing...';
        }
     }
```